# AssertionError in Unit Test | Response Data suggests otherwise

Tags: python, flask

Hey so I'm running Unit Tests on my 'Logout' function and am receiving an AssertionError where I don't understand why it exists.

Here's the error (response data cut down for readability):

```
self.assertIn(b'Logged out', response.data)
AssertionError: b'Logged out' not found in b'<!DOCTYPE html>
...
<li>Logged Out </li>
...
```

I'd expect this not to return an AssertionError, seeing as the text 'Logged out' is found in the response data.

EDIT: Here's my test function if that's of any help

```
def test_logout(self):
        self.app.get('/register', follow_redirects = True)
        self.register("username", "email@email.com", "password", "password", "preference")
        self.app.get('/login', follow_redirects = True)
        self.login("username", "password")
        response = self.app.get('/logout', follow_redirects = True)
        self.assertIn(b'Logged out', response.data)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The assertion error suggests that the O in out is capitalised yet you are testing against an uncapitalised o.

Python is case sensitive when making assertions as it should be so update your test to:

`self.assertIn(b'Logged Out', response.data)`